# Преобразование с object в float

Tags: c#, datagridview

При попытке преобразования object в float получаю следующую ошибку:

> > System.InvalidCastException: Заданное приведение является недопустимым.
> > в Lab2_alg_.Form1.Add(MenuOfRestaurant[] menu) в D:\College\labs\Lab2(alg)\Lab2(alg)\Form1.cs:строка 25
> > в Lab2_alg_.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в D:\College\labs\Lab2(alg)\Lab2(alg)\Form1.cs:строка 34

```
menu[i].weight = (float)dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
```

Comment: можете попробовать испоьзовать `float.Parse(dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString())`

Comment: Потому что у вас в ячейке не float, и вы даже не сказали, что там.

Comment: @KuzCode не работает, так же выдает ошибку о невозможности конвертирования

Comment: @aepot не совсем ясно, о чем вы говорите. datagrid1.value возвращает тип object.

Comment: Да, но внутри лежит то, что вы туда положили.

Comment: Сделайте ``GetType()`` к вашему dataGridView1[j, i].Value чтобы для начала узнать какой там тип данный, прежде чем в лоб делать ``(float)``